# Import Excel with HTML Format to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, html, datatable

I've been searching in the net with no answers
How do you import a .xls file that is made of `<table>,<th>,<tr>,<td>` tags to DataTable?

Comment: I guess you need to parse it and manualy fill DataTable

Comment: Are there any samples, I'm still a beginner at this. Thanks. @Stecya

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655603/html-agility-pack-parsing-tables/655849#655849

Comment: Where are you getting the XLS file from? You can't, in general, assume all XLS consumers can read HTML (as you're discovering) so you should get whoever's generating it to [generate a real XLS file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the HTML is well formed you can try to load it as XML. Expanding a bit with a very simple example:

```
        System.Xml.Linq.XDocument html = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (@"[xls doc]");
        //this will pull all the Table Headers. 
        var q = from th in html.Descendants ("th") select (string)th.Value;
```

Answer (score -2):

I would use [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)

[This](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20read%20excel) should get you started.

Comment: He's not asking about reading real Excel files, though - he wants to read a fake XLS file that someone's made by writing an HTML table.

Comment: I doubt that he can use PHP to import anything to ADO.NET DataTable, so -1