# How to parse html table using xml?

Tags: asp.net, html, xml

I'm having an html table of the format

```
<table>
 <th>
     <td> td1 </td>
     <td> td2 </td>
     <td> td3 </td>
     <td> td4 </td>
     <td> td5 </td>
     <td> td6 </td>
     <td> td7 </td>
     <td> td8 </td>
     <td> td9 </td>
     <td> td10 <td>
   </th>
</table>
```

I need to parse through the cells in each row within the table body. I looped through the row using a javascript and inorder to save the html content i'm using webmethod( because on saving, my page will reload and i will lose my html table, to avoid that i stored it on a session using webmethod and this too happens within my javascript call) . The issue is my client side script is getting skipped at times and i'm not able to save my html content. So i thought of to send the html content as a whole in one script call and do the parsing in server-side.

Now, i need to know how to parse it from server-side. Can some-body help me to parse it using xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Agility pack - parsing tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655603/html-agility-pack-parsing-tables)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should try [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

from CodePlex

> What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?
>
> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).