# Html Agility Pack loop through table rows and columns

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have a table like this

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table2">
    <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Age
        </th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Mario
        </td>
        <th>Age: 78
        </td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Jane
        </td>
        <td>Age: 67
        </td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>James
        </td>
        <th>Age: 92
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And want to use HTML Agility Pack to parse it. I have tried this code to no avail:

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='table2']//tr"))
{
    foreach (HtmlNode col in row.SelectNodes("//td"))
    { 
        Response.Write(col.InnerText); 
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you describe what does not work?

Comment: I get an indefinite loop

Comment: It works for me (well, not exactly, I get the names Mario/Jane/James repeating 4 times).  Note that '//td' _does not select from the current node only_ (as you might expect) _but from the DocumentNode_.   What version of HtmlAgilityPack are you using?

Comment: Hmm that looks like your .NET version.  Did you get HtmlAgilityPack via NuGet?

Comment: You are right this is the version: 1.4.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to provide the full xpath. I got the full xpath by using Firebug from a suggestion by @Coda (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104048/1238850) and I ended up with this code:

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[@id='table2']/tbody/tr"))
{
    HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("td");
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        { Response.Write("Person Name : " + cells[i].InnerText + "<br>"); }
        else {
            Response.Write("Other attributes are: " + cells[i].InnerText + "<br>"); 
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure it can be written way better than this but it is working for me now.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just select the `td`s directly?

```
foreach (HtmlNode col in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='table2']//tr//td"))
    Response.Write(col.InnerText);
```

Alternately, if you really need the `tr`s separately for some other processing, drop the `//` and do:

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='table2']//tr"))
    foreach (HtmlNode col in row.SelectNodes("td"))
        Response.Write(col.InnerText);
```

Of course that will only work if the `td`s are direct children of the `tr`s but they should be, right?

---

EDIT:

```
var cols = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='table2']//tr//td");
for (int ii = 0; ii < cols.Count; ii=ii+2)
{
    string name = cols[ii].InnerText.Trim();
    int age = int.Parse(cols[ii+1].InnerText.Split(' ')[1]);
}
```

There's probably a more impressive way to do this with LINQ.

Comment: Yes I want to do use each column for processing as you can see the second column is a mixture of numbers and text, I would like to extract the number. The page just circles and no result after I tried this code.

Answer (score 4):

I've run the code and it displays only the *Names*, which is correct, because the *Ages* are defined using invalid HTML: `<th></td>` (probably a typo).

By the way, the code can be simplified to only one loop:

```
foreach (var cell in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='table2']/tr/td"))
{
    Response.Write(cell.InnerText);
}
```

Here's the code I used to test: http://pastebin.com/euzhUAAh

Answer (score 1):

I did the same project with this:

```
        private List<PhrasalVerb> ExtractVerbsFromMainPage(string content)
    {
        var verbs =new List<PhrasalVerb>(); ;
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(content);
        var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='idioms-table']//tr");
        rows.RemoveAt(0); //remove header
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            var cols = row.SelectNodes("td");
            verbs.Add(new PhrasalVerb { 
            Uid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = cols[0].InnerHtml,
            Definition = cols[1].InnerText,
            Count =int.TryParse(cols[2].InnerText,out _) == true ? Convert.ToInt32(cols[2].InnerText) : 0
            });
        }
        return verbs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Table1> getTable1Data(string result)
{
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(result);

    var table1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").First();
    var tbody = table1.ChildNodes["tbody"];
    var lst = new List<Table1>();
    foreach (var row in tbody.ChildNodes.Where(r => r.Name == "tr"))
    {
        var tbl1 = new Table1();
        var columnsArray = row.ChildNodes.Where(c => c.Name == "td").ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                tbl1.Course = columnsArray[i].InnerText.Trim();
            if (i == 1)
                tbl1.Count = columnsArray[i].InnerText.Trim();
            if (i == 2)
                tbl1.Correct = columnsArray[i].InnerText.Trim();
        }
        lst.Add(tbl1);
    }
    return lst;
}

public class Table1
{
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public string Correct { get; set; }
}
```