# Create an excel file from HTML

Tags: c#, html, excel, stream

I get an html file from the content of the HttpResponseMessage

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, myUrl);
var response = client.SendAsync(request);
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Then I'm trying to create an excel file

```
using(var Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)
{
   Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
   Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(content);
}
```

And here I get an error message

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

But if I manually copy all content from the response and create a file and then load it as

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.html");
```

it works perfect. Can anyone explain please is it possible to create a Workbook from html string without saving a file?

Comment: What is the value of `content`? Is it a filename? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx

Comment: This is the html page content. I mean "\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" >\n\n<head>\n<style type=\"text/css\">\nbr {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}\n</style>\n<!--<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">-->\n</head>\n<body>\ ... ... ... What is displayed on the html page.

Comment: `Open` expects a filename. You can't pass it any old string.

Comment: Got it. Many thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

`xlApp.Workbooks.Open` needs to be passed a file path to work.

If you don't have a file path, you will want to use `xlApp.Workbooks.Add` instead (and **not** passing any parameters). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add.aspx for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately xlApp.Workbooks.Add() doesn't work in my case (fails with the same exception). It looks like the best solution is to use something like HTML Agility Pack to parse HTML file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968729/html-agility-pack-loop-through-table-rows-and-columns)