# HTML | <td> - Removing Everything from InnerHTML Under Tags

Tags: c#, html, parsing, text

I have a few td elements that have some text in them, and some contain also a `br` and a `span` elements.

I want to keep only that text. For those that have an `&nbsp` in it, so I used a regular expression (`<[^>]+>|&nbsp`) to remove it, but in the `td` elements that contain more things, it's not enough.

When I print the InnerHTML of the tds it looks like this - 
above - a `<td>` without the extras, below - with:

[image]

What is the way to remove everything but the text?

Comment: You should use Html parser, don't parse html with regex ! Post your code and exactly what you want

Comment: try use HtmlAgilityPack like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655603/html-agility-pack-parsing-tables

Comment: I'm using the HtmlAgilityPack, and I'm selecting the td as a node.
But I want the output from it to be a string.