# HtmlAgilityPack - Extract links from a specific table

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I'm having some trouble finding the exact way to parse for links from a site. [Using firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104048/3112698), the table's exact xPath is :

```
/html/body/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table
```

It also has an id ='ctl00_cp1_GridView1' (which hasn't been exactly helpful).

All I want to do is find all of the  links in the first  and add them to a list.

Here's my current code snippet (with some help [from this post](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/10363):

```
protected void btnSubmitURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> siteList = new List<string>();
        int counter = 1;

        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(txtURL.Text);
        var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/body/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[@id='ctl00_cp1_GridView1']/tbody");
        HtmlNodeCollection rows = table.SelectNodes("./tr");
        if (rows != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
            {
                HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes("./td[1]");
                if (cols != null)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; j++)
                    {
                        HtmlNode aTags = cols[i].SelectSingleNode("./a[@id='NormalColoredFont']");
                        if (aTags != null)
                        {
                            siteList.Add(counter + ". " + aTags.InnerHtml + " - " + aTags.Attributes["href"].Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        lblOutput.Text = siteList.Count.ToString();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I keep getting an Null Exception error out right at the HtmlNodeCollection rows because it can't find that specific table. I've tried searching via the table id but that hasn't helped either.

Any help with getting to that table would be appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using the id of `ctl00_cp1_GridView1`?  That will get you much closer to the element in question than that path (which is *extremely* likely to change, moreso than the ID).

Comment: There is a bug in the HtmlAgilityPack when using multiple indexers, I've seen this before. Not sure why it happens. Why indeed not just use `//table[@id='ctl00_cp1_GridView1']//a[@href]` to grab all links under the table?

Comment: I've tried using the the suggestion made by jessehouwing and I was able to get to the table, but unfortunately I am unable to retrieve all of the links. So I switched back to just using the table id as casperOne suggested and the code now runs through until it comes to extracting all of the <a> tags. It hits the table by id, selects all of the <tr> tags, then <td[1]> tags, before coming up empty by the <a> tags. Does anyone think the issue may be the <td[1]>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to finally extract all of the links using [the example used from Scott Mitchell](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx). His example is as followed:

```
var linksOnPage = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
              where lnks.Name == "a" && 
                   lnks.Attributes["href"] != null && 
                   lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0
              select new
              {
                 Url = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value,
                 Text = lnks.InnerText
              };
```

Thanks to jessehouwing and casperOne for responding quickly!